# Python Detect shape over another shape

Tags: python, class, tkinter, shapes

I need to know how to detect if an oval that is being draged with the mouse enter over another shape(rectangle).

```
class Bloque(): # Creates a block
   def __init__(self, lista, ventana):
       self.espacio = ventana # assings the canvas
       box = self.espacio.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 0) # creates the block
       self.espacio.tag_bind(box, '<Enter>', lambda e: print("Passed over"))
```

This detects if the mouse pass over the block but when I drag other shape over the block, It's not detected. So how can I make that when I drag other shape over the block send me a message?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the oval ID is stored in `self.oval`.  Note also that I've stored the box ID in an instance variable `self.box` instead of a local variable `box`.

```
class Bloque(): # Creates a block
   def __init__(self, lista, ventana):
       self.espacio = ventana # assings the canvas
       self.box = self.espacio.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 0) # creates the block
       self.espacio.tag_bind(self.box, '<B1-Motion>', self.detectIntersection)

   def detectIntersection(self, event):
       overlaps = self.espacio.find_overlapping(*self.espacio.bbox(box))
       if self.oval in overlaps:
          print("Passed over")
```